# Magento Block not Loading

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm building my first module in Magento and have a couple question related to the process.

Before I attempted a module, I just had a template and was loading it into `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\local.xml` with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" template="mgw/mwCartRebuild.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Life was good and everything worked until I decided I need to extend the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar` class.

So I create a Module to do so. Here is my code.

**Block** `app\code\local\mgw\Cart\Block\ModalCart.php`

```
<?php 
class mgw_Cart_Block_Modal_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar{
    public function __construct(){
        perent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('mgw/mwCartRebuild.phtml');
    }
}
```

**config.xml** `app\code\local\mgw\Cart\etc\config.xml`

```
<config>
    <global>
        <modules>
            <mgw_Cart>
                <version>0.0.0</version>
            </mgw_Cart>
        </modules>
        <blocks>
            <mgw_Cart>
                <class>mgw_Cart_Block_Modal_Cart</class>
            </mgw_Cart>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <cart>
                <class>mgw_Cart_Helper</class>
            </cart>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**New local.xml** `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="cart/modal_cart"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**Module xml** `app\etc\modules\mgw_Cart.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <mgw_Cart>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends />
        </mgw_Cart>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now my template won't load. I've checked the Admin to see if my Module is loading and it is listed. So why won't my template load?

My questions are:

- Can I even extend a core block like I'm trying?
- How can I get my Block/Template to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to Magento and i can help you with your problem.
First of all i would recommend to use a clear and simply nomenclature for your custom modules and files, "ModalCart.php" can be renamed as "Modalcart.php", avoiding any reference problem.

If you want to extend/override a Mage class you need to specify it in the config.xml of your module, like this:

```
<blocks>
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <cart_sidebar>PkgName_ModuleName_Block_YourClassThatOverrides</cart_sidebar>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</blocks>
```

in  the above code you are declaring that you are going to rewrite the checkout/cart_sidebar block with your new class.

So this was the config.xml, now you are going to create the class that overrides. In your module's Block directory create the class file .php that extends/rewrite the core class:

```
<?php
  class PkgName_ModuleName_Block_YourClassThatOverrides extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar {
      // check for the methods to rewrite or create new methods
  }
```

and for your last question about how to set a specific Template or Layout:
Before start coding my personal advice is to study the same thing 3 or 4 times from different sources and then code it for 3 or 4 times untill you can understand and memorize all the content.
So for the layout/template section i suggest to read this Alan Storm thread: 
https://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates/

Comment: Thanks Marco, this is great information. There are so many incomplete sources for learning magento 1. Super hard to piece everything together. I will give all of this a go soon.

Comment: it is hard because there is not a free straight line guide to follow, it 's like they did  `explode(" " ,MagentoGuide1.x)` . Just keep exercising and you will climb that knowlEdge. I'm happy to have solved your problem.

Comment: Still having problems getting a custom block to load on `<reference name="after_body_start">` I can get a controller to load a Block but not from this reference.

Comment: NVM. I figured it out. My block class file was not named correctly.